# How can I ensure my cat won't resent me after being alone for an 8-hour work day?

Tags: cats, psychology, toys

I was raised with cats although my parents were always home so my cats adored them and there was always somebody around to pet them.

As I go into the world, I'll be single.  I mean, I'm young so it's okay, but I still want a cat, or two, since I'll be living alone.  Working an an electrical engineer, I'll most likely be at my job for 40+ hours a week, normal job stuff.

Do I  need to make sure that my cats are entertained while I'm away?  Is there anything I can do to ensure my cat will still sit next to me on the couch when I come home?

Comment: Are you having problems with that now?  I do not think I have ever heard of cats holding a grudge (at least not more than a few minutes) about being gone for short periods like a workday.

Comment: @Critters No, I don't have a cat right now, I'm just worried about it happening when I get one.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry. We're both gone all day and when we come home, our cats are lovely (they really want to cuddle and be pet) and sit on the couch with us (I have one on each side right now as I'm typing this).

Comment: For cats we have seen holding grudges are pretty rare - it usually takes long trips (couple weeks), and even then the grudge is usually loud complaining or deliberately turning their back, usually following room to room so they know you can *see* them snubbing you.  And such usually only lasts a few hours.  They usually want interaction more then they want to hold a grudge.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience cats are pretty self-sufficient. As long as they have food, water, and a litterbox they can be fine on their own for a work day - although a selection of toys helps.

Kittens are more demanding - if you're looking at getting a kitten, I'd recommend getting two. Littermates will already know each other, but kittens rarely have issues adjusting to new feline company, where older cats can be quite challenging if they're not used to having other cats around.

Whether kittens or cats, once they've adjusted to their new surroundings they will keep each other company.

Your main problem isn't likely to be your cat or cats resenting you being away. It's more likely to be boredom-induced damage or the demands for attention the cat makes when you get home (this one's been the case for me with every cat I've had).

Answer (score 7):

Cats tend to sleep more during the day, so they aren't likely to pine for you. Just be sure to give them lots of attention when you get home.

In my experience, cats tend to adjust to the amount of attention they get (assuming they were properly socialised as kittens). When you give them a lot of attention, they want a lot of attention. Ignore them for too long, and they tend to be a bit aloof.

Comment: Thanks! thats good to hear.  I accidentally asked this using an account I don't use anymore.  Thanks for the answer though, I wish I could accept it.

Comment: indeed- I'm glad you mentioned kittens, because that's when it is most important to be around them.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that cats don't react in that way - they don't mind being left to go to work.  An additional help is if you adopt a matched pair when you do get cats, as they can hang out with each other during the day and react to each other rather than get into trouble on their own.

Answer (score 3):

I had a cat which I lost few months ago. He felt really alone when we were out for a long time. This time, we have brought two cats which always stick together. They need us, but up to a certain limit. When we are away, they care and groom each other. It was even advantageous when one of them was ill; the other had taken care of him. So try to bring a pair if you can afford.